# Sentry/NLog Integration Not Logging to Sentry

Tags: asp.net, nlog, sentry

I am using the latest Sentry/NLog packages (as shown below) but for some reason, my errors are begin logged to NLog but not to Sentry.

**I can see that Sentry is being initialized, but it never logs anything!  Meanwhile, the errors are being logged to NLog without issue.**

These are my relevant packages:

```
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.3" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="NLog" version="4.7.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Sentry" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Sentry.NLog" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Sentry.PlatformAbstractions" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Sentry.Protocol" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Immutable" version="1.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
```

This is my NLog config file (I've removed my DSN for security reasons):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwConfigExceptions="true">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="Sentry.NLog" />
  </extensions>
  <targets async="true">
    <target name="SentryLogger" xsi:type="Sentry"
      dsn="{removed for security reasons...}"
      environment="${appsetting:item=Environment:default=Staging}"
      InitializeSdk="true"
      layout="${message}"
      breadcrumbLayout="${message}"
      minimumBreadcrumbLevel="Debug"
      minimumEventLevel="Error">
      <options
            attachStacktrace="true"
            sendDefaultPii="true"
            shutdownTimeoutSeconds="5"
            includeEventDataOnBreadcrumbs="true" />
    </target>
    
    <target name="default" xsi:type="File"
      fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
      archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/archive-log/app-log.{#}.txt"
      archiveEvery="Day"
      archiveNumbering="Rolling"
      maxArchiveFiles="30" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="default" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="SentryLogger" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Is there any reason why NLog would be working but not Sentry?  I have other projects in the same solution which correctly log to both Sentry and NLog, just not this one!

[image]

**Edit:** I checked the NLog Internal log and it seems like it's writing to Sentry, but it never shows up in the UI on Sentry.  There don't appear to be any errors in the internal log file, either.

```
2020-06-11 16:53:31.5829 Trace AsyncWrapper(Name=default): Throttled timer scheduled
2020-06-11 16:53:31.5829 Trace AsyncWrapper(Name=SentryLogger): Throttled timer scheduled
2020-06-11 16:53:31.5920 Trace AsyncWrapper(Name=SentryLogger): Writing 1 events (Timer)
2020-06-11 16:53:31.5920 Trace AsyncWrapper(Name=default): Writing 1 events (Timer)
```

**Edit:** After updating the Sentry.NLog package via Nuget from 2.1.1 to 2.1.4, I am receiving a `System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.` error in the NLog internal log file!  I was able to resolve the issue by adding `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =             SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;` to my Global.asax.cs file!  Problem solved!  Thank you, @Rolf Kristensen!

```
2020-06-25 16:50:55.8958 Debug Event queued up.
2020-06-25 16:50:55.9198 Debug Configuring the scope.
2020-06-25 16:50:56.2788 Debug Event 1338f238cd484cc7a0a288133306718c in-flight to Sentry. #1 in queue.
2020-06-25 16:50:56.4968 Error Error while processing event 1338f238cd484cc7a0a288133306718c: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sentry.Internal.Http.GzipBufferedRequestBodyHandler.<SendAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sentry.Internal.Http.RetryAfterHandler.<SendAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sentry.Internal.Http.HttpTransport.<CaptureEventAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Sentry.Internal.BackgroundWorker.<WorkerAsync>d__18.MoveNext(). #1 in queue.
```

Comment: Checked the internal log? https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Internal-logging

Comment: @Julian Great point!  I checked there but I don't see any errors.  It looks like it says it's writing to Sentry but I never see it on the Sentry UI.  I've updated the question with the relevant logs.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the source gives some insights: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/master/src/Sentry.NLog/SentryTarget.cs. Note also the returns in `Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)`

Comment: @Julian Thanks - I was looking at the source file, too, and I don't think `logEvent?.Message` would be null because it's logging the error in my NLog file `Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.ApplicationException: Test exception; please disregard...`.  As for the `hub?.IsEnabled`, I am not sure how to confirm that value, but I can't think of any reason why it should be disabled anyway (but I would like to check if I knew where to look).

Comment: @user1477388 Sentry debug logging is now redirected to NLog Internal Logging with latest https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sentry.NLog Could you try the new version and check the output from the NLog InternalLogger ?

Comment: @RolfKristensen Awesome, man!  I updated the question with the results after updating the package.  It was apparently a TLS issue whereby Sentry was requiring TLS 1.2 (understandably so).  Thanks, again, for your help tracking down this issue!

Comment: in my case was the addblocker ....

Comment: This just helped me out a lot!
You need to write an answer for this. There is no problem writing an answer your own question. It helps others more easily find the solution.

Comment: @GregWoods Good idea.  Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After updating the Sentry.NLog package via Nuget from 2.1.1 to 2.1.4, I was still receiving a *System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.* error in the NLog internal log file!

However, I was able to resolve this issue by adding this to my **Global.asax.cs** file!

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Problem solved! Thank you, @Rolf Kristensen!

Comment: There is also now SecurityProtocolType.Tls13. I added that to the end as well

Answer (score 2):

If it just silently fails to send error to Sentry, with no entries in internal log, I would check your sentry DSN, and then double and triple check it :)
Make sure you are looking at correct project when looking for errors in Sentry, and environment dropdown is set to All environments.
If you are 100% sure DSN is correct, try adding atribute throwExceptions="true" to nlog tag. This might bring some new clues.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it didn't send the exception event to Sentry because it is somehow swallowed by an existing logging provider (it could be the default). The fix was to update the Program.cs file to explicitly use NLog then removing the default Logging object in appsettings.json.

Found the fix here: https://programmingcsharp.com/nlog-net-core/