# Sentry Not Logging Errors in WebForms App

Tags: asp.net, webforms, sentry

My WebForms app targets .NET 4.7.2.  I installed Sentry 2.1.1 via NuGet.

When my application hits an unhandled exception, the exception should be captured and logged to Sentry according to my DSN.

As you can see below, my breakpoint is hit and the exception is present at the time of capture, but the error is never logged.

**Why aren't my errors logging to Sentry?**

[image]

```
using System;
using Sentry;

public partial class FloorForceWeb : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private IDisposable _sentry;

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup

        // Set up the sentry SDK
        _sentry = SentrySdk.Init(o =>
        {
            o.Dsn = new Dsn("removed for security reasons...");
            o.Environment = "Development";
        });
    }
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _sentry.Dispose();
    }

    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();
        SentrySdk.CaptureException(exception);
    }

    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

**Note:** This code was adapted from https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet-samples/blob/master/AspNetMvc5Ef6/Global.asax.cs

[image]

**Edit:** I've added `o.Debug = true;` and `o.DiagnosticsLevel = Sentry.Protocol.SentryLevel.Debug;` to by `SentrySdk.Init()` but nothing is logged in the debug console:

[image]

Comment: From looking at your setup, it should be working. Is it possible you're testing it only under the debugger and killing the process before `Application_End` runs? Disposing the SDK is what makes sure events are sent to Sentry before the app exits. Lastly, does that box need a proxy to access the Internet?

Comment: @BrunoGarcia I have allowed about 30 seconds after the exception was captured before stopping the debugger.  The application is running from my development machine which does not require any proxy to access the internet.  Other projects in my solution (a console app, for example) running the same version of .NET and Sentry log errors correctly.  There must be something about this application which is preventing it from working.  Is there anything else I should check?

Comment: The SDK has a `Debug` mode: https://docs.sentry.io/error-reporting/configuration/?platform=csharp#debug By default it prints to Console but under the debugger when using IIS Express it will print to the output Window on Visual Studio. Take a look at the logs there: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/d2c16b3f837ce24778f49bc73ec39ab74f9c8470/src/Sentry/SentryOptionsExtensions.cs#L157-L167

Comment: @BrunoGarcia Nothing notable is being logged to the console when I enable `debug` mode.  However, I did realize that the `CaptureException` method returns an event ID of `2b46736537ef4c0e8dd60f4bced8a236`.  Maybe someone on the Sentry team can see what's happening by looking at this ID?

Comment: You can search by that id. It should find the event. Double check the DSN is the right one, to the project you want. If you paste a link to the project I can search the event. Oh, the SDK logs should show that the event got captured and print the event id. I thought the Id you pasted was taken from the debug log. Please add the SDK debug log to the issue

Comment: @BrunoGarcia It doesn't seem to be searchable: https://sentry.adhawk.engineering/broadlume/floorforce/?query=2b46736537ef4c0e8dd60f4bced8a236.  I've added a screenshot of my debug log from the output panel to my question above but I'm not seeing any messages which I would expect to see like, "Logging enabled with ConsoleDiagnosticLogger and min level: {0}"

Comment: I assumed it was sentry.io. I can't see events in your on premise Sentry installation. Non of the other options from "Show output from:" in Visual Studio print out anything? It should be printing messages there, just as if you write `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` by yourself, you should be able to see it in VS.

Comment: @BrunoGarcia I can't find any other logs in the other "Show output from:" options.  The only thing I can think of is that this is a WebForms "site" not WebForms "application."  The difference is, there is no .csproj file; it's simply a collection of .aspx pages.  It does contain a web.config and global.asax; it also supports NLog and the NewRelic NLog sink works just fine.  Just not Sentry for some reason!  I think our solution will just be to use NLog and the NewRelic sink for this project.  I've greatly appreciated your assistance!

Comment: It should work for Sentry too. Feel free to raise an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet ideally link to a repository that has a project reproducing the error so one can pull the code and run to see what is going on.

Comment: @BrunoGarcia A recent version of the Sentry.NLog package on NuGet now logs errors to the internal log!  Due to this update, I was able to see that the issue was caused by my old WebForms app not using TLS 1.2 which is required by Sentry (justifiably so).  Thanks for your help!  Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62331587/sentry-nlog-integration-not-logging-to-sentry?noredirect=1#comment110673484_62331587