# Web Application not logging errors to Sentry when deployed on Azure App

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, sentry

I am using Sentry free account for logging error in my application. The logging works fine on my dev environment but when I deploy app on Azure, errors are not pushed on sentry. I checked file logs and the Sentry client CaptureException method is working fine and returning a SentryId as well but when I check at Sentry.io, no exception is logged there.
It is an asp. net application.
.Net Framework: 4. 6. 1
Sentry Client Version: 3. 9. 0. 0

This is my method that logs exceptions to sentry:

```
public void LogException(Exception ex)
        {
            
                try
                {
                    if (ex == null) return;
                    var sentryId = SentrySdk.CaptureException(ex);
                    LogManager.Info(typeof(SentryManager),
                    $"SentrySdk.CaptureException(ex) called successfully. SentryId: {sentryId}");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    LogManager.Error(typeof(SentryManager), $"SentryManager Exception - {e.Message + e.InnerException}", null);
                }
        }
```

I have checked my Azure logs and nothing found related to Sentry. Please suggest what can I do to debug my issue,
Thanks.

--EDIT--

I am able to get the error message. I am getting this error: "Failed to report an error on a session because there is none active.System.Object[]"

Can anyone suggest what to do to avoid this?

--EDIT 2--

Error Captured:
Could not load file or assembly ‘System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1,

Comment: You can set the SDK in debug mode to see what it's doing: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/configuration/options/#debug

Comment: @BrunoGarcia thank you for the response. but this was not the issue. posting the answer in case someone else is stuck on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, I had to identify the error that was causing the issue. For this, I wrote a simple logger for logging messages generated from Sentry SDK. (Source: [Sentry Not Logging Errors in WebForms App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62393682/sentry-not-logging-errors-in-webforms-app))

```
public class SentryDiagnosticLogger : IDiagnosticLogger {
    public SentryDiagnosticLogger()
    {
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(SentryLevel level)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Log(SentryLevel logLevel, string message, Exception exception = null, params object[] args)
    {
        if (exception != null)
            throw new Exception("Sentry Exception occurred", exception);
    }
}
```

My SDK initialization code looks like this:

```
SentrySdk.Init(o =>
    {
        o.Dsn = config;
        o.Environment = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tavrtalk:Environment"];
        o.Debug = true;
        o.DiagnosticLevel = SentryLevel.Debug;
        o.DiagnosticLogger = new SentryDiagnosticLogger();
    });
```

Finally, I got the error:

> Could not load file or assembly
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1

I had 5.0.0 version in my project. So, I updated binding redirects in my host application and Sentry SDK automatically picked the update version of System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe assembly. I added the following configurations in my web.config file:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="*************" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

This was the reason why the Sentry was working fine on dev because web.config for my dev had this binding redirect but the deployed web.config didn't.

Comment: This Log method is called by the SDK to communicate what's going on within it. And not the exception in your app. Throwing an exception from it like that is likely going to cause an infinite loop since the SDK might catch that and then use that exact Diagnostic Logger to log it back out again. I don't recommend this.  Please check docs for it here: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/configuration/diagnostic-logger/

Comment: @BrunoGarcia I dont understand how it would be an infinite loop? since we have overriden the logger behavior, instead of catching the exception, the logger will throw the exception which then will be handled in my own code!

Comment: The SDK itself calls LogError on the diagnostic logger. It does that within try blocks. That logger interface exists for diagnosing issues with the SDK itself. It's possible the SDK will catch and rethrow from the top try/catch blocks and it'll leak out to your own code but that can crash your app

Comment: @BrunoGarcia thank you for pointing out. I understand now. Will look into this in more details.